# Browser tab icon not showing after pushed to Github Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

My browser tab icon is not showing up after I push my repo to github. It shows up fine when I test it on localhost.

[Left shows my website hosted on github, right shows my website on local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yjpr.png)

Here's my code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="public/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Futura-Book";
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript -->
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[and here's my file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEFRB.png)

Would appreciate any help and suggestions, thank you!

Comment: check the developer tools console for errors - chances are the path having `public` in it is wrong - i.e. it should be `href="favicon.ico"`

Comment: How did you set this project up? Normally with a Vue CLI created app, you'd have the `index.html` and any other static files in the `public` directory

Answer (score 0):

The icon should be in the root of dist folder. So removing the public from the path should fix the problem.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

If it does not work, change the name of favicon.ico to something else.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="something.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```